# Notification email from stackoverflow contains "<3" after zip code

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, notifications, email

I noticed "<3" appears at the very end of the my stackoverflow notification emails (after the zip code). Is this problem related to gmail?

Comment: +1, actually +1s for all answers as well! what a great addition to the end of an email...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Stack Overflow loves you! <3**

This is the actual code in the email:

```
<span title="because we care" style="color:maroon">&lt;3</span>
```

So to answer your question, this is intentional and not a problem with GMail.

Comment: Francesca has developed emotions.

Comment: I am now jealous and in a rage.

Comment: Next time I should tilt my screen 90° counter-clockwise before asking a question. :P

Comment: Surprising that you've never seen an emoticon heart before.

Comment: There is a first time for everything.

Comment: You mean, Stack Overflow sends out HTML messages? Ugh!

Comment: This is the sort of nice touch that makes you love a site!

Comment: @kjanz1899 "♥" instead of "<3" could have done the trick too I guess.

Answer (score 18):

each email is baked with love!

Comment: Oh! Oh! Oh, man, your're actually here! I'm not worthy! I'm not worthy! [source: http://snltranscripts.jt.org/89/89mwaynesworld.phtml]

Comment: This is the sort of nice touch that makes you love a site!

Answer (score 5):

StackOverflow loves you.

Answer (score 5):

I feel so warm and fuzzy. I love you too, Stack Overflow! <3

Comment: I less-than-three Stack Overflow.