# Why does <3 show up on Stack Overflow e-mails?

Tags: discussion, email, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification email from stackoverflow contains “<3” after zip code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13014/notification-email-from-stackoverflow-contains-3-after-zip-code)

When I received an e-mail from the Stack Overflow team this morning, there was a niggling "<3" at the end. I've seen this in various e-mails, not just from Stack Overflow.

Here's what it it looks like:

> stackoverflow.com LLC, PO Box 1361, El Cerrito CA 94530 <3

Here's the source:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
stackoverflow.com LLC, PO Box 1361, El Cerrito CA 94530 
<span title="because we care" style="color:maroon">&lt;3</span></span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What could cause this? Is it an HTML character that Outlook does not render correctly? Or is Jeff trying to send me secret messages?

Comment: It means heart.

Comment: I think it's Jeff trying to send you secret messages.

Comment: Even, you know better than to ask this here...

Comment: What is love? Baby, don't hurt me.

Comment: I know this just got migrated, but the reason I asked on SO instead of Meta was that I searched google for "<3" and found nothing. It wasn't until writing up the question that I searched on "&lt;3" that I figured out that it was a heart. I thought that it would be a useful (albeit fun) question to ask there.

Comment: I'm almost sure I've seen this question before, but it's not in the 'email' tag. And as you said, it's hard to search for.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13014/notification-email-from-stackoverflow-contains-3-after-zip-code

Comment: Unicode​​​​ FTW! ♥

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a sideways heart. The person sending the email is being cute.

Answer (score 14):

It's because they care, but only to the extent of 2 care units (less than 3).

Answer (score 3):

**Stack Overflow loves you! <3**

This is the actual code in the email:

```
<span title="because we care" style="color:maroon">&lt;3</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its the symbol for love, a heart, expressing gratitude for reading their email and being a member of this community. <3