# The "total rep" line of the reputation audit features incorrect colons/braces

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-audit, special-characters

From my reputation audit for tex.sx:

```
** rep today: 262
** rep this week (2011-12-04 - 2011-12-10): 262
** rep this month (2011-12-01 - 2011-12-31): 752
** rep this quarter (2011-10-01 - 2011-12-31): 8113
** rep this year (2011-01-01 - 2011-12-31): 31462
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 39075 :)
```

Shouldn't the last line read (colon repositioned, closing brace removed):

```
** total rep: 39075
```

EDIT: To the person who downvoted: I hope you didn't regard my question as frivolous -- I had suspected that the colons/braces from the audit's date specifications had crept into the "total rep" line.

Comment: I think it's a smiley :)

Comment: @ChrisF: Could be ... but I'm not totally convinced. :-)

Comment: They need to counter all those sad faces after the dates above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13016/59303) for a different case I believe it's intentional.

It's a smiley :)

Comment: Well ... seems so. Unless an SO official confirms it, I'm going to accept your answer. And thanks for pointing me to a not-so-obvious duplicate question.

Comment: @lockstep, because we care! (: