# New email template: small typo or you love us? :p

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, email, spelling, email-notification

I want to say that I was very surprised to see the new email template, you did great work as usual.

I just wanted to point out that there is a small `<3` at the bottom of the email. I guess that's not a typo, but anyway, it might be.

[image]

See you on Stackoverflow!

Comment: The fact that is is red is no clue then? :-) <3

Comment: You mean that dark, dried blood red, @martijn?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: [Colour is all relative](http://vimeo.com/26788521).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look closely at any email with the old design. :)

<3

Comment: lol, I never noticed that before.

Answer (score 6):

Not a typo… [***We really mean it!***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13014/98786)

> **Stack Overflow loves you! <3**
>
> This is the actual code in the email:
>
> `<span title="because we care" style="color:maroon">&lt;3</span>`

So to answer your question, this is intentional and not a problem with the email.